# Live updates using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'd like to make a div's contents update as soon as a new row appears in a MySQL database (I'm making a webmail app). As I'm writing this, it's becoming more clear to me that I can't send some sort of server message to the client asking it to update, so I've come to the conclusion that the best way to have live updates is to use a jQuery ajax call, triggered by a `setTimeOut` event.

My question is: is there a better way to do this? Or if I have to use `setTimeOut`, what time interval should I set to keep the optimal balance between server usage and update times?

The code run every AJAX call will be one query (to fetch new mails) and a loop to post it to a `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think HTML5 [WebSockets](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) might be what you're looking for...

There's an example usage [here](http://bohuco.net/blog/2010/07/html5-websockets-example/).

As you mention, support is limited to Chrome and Safari at present.

Comment: Thanks for the idea - I'll take a look at websockets when HTML5 becomes more mainstream, however, for the time being I'd like to keep compatability with current HTML4 browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best way unless you use Stream Hub or a COMET server which is reverse AJAX :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll stick with AJAX. Would you be able to recommend a good time interval? Would 30 seconds be ok?

Comment: well i have dashboards where i'm using 5 seconds, but these arent large sites, so if your site gets big then you may use 1 minute. Who needs to check mail more than once a minute :)